# Programmatically generating Cassandra CQL for Clojure type using Alia/Hayt

Tags: clojure

I have a blank Cassandra 2.1 data store and I am trying to populate it programmatically, from the keyspace down in Clojure, using Alia and Hayt. This is being used as the data store behind a web service end point that receives JSON data from clients.

I'd like to be able to parse the incoming data to a Clojure instance, change that data a little (adding another key, value pair to a map, for instance) and insert the data into the data store in such a way that I can retrieve it later as a Clojure instance.

Everything is working as I expect except for my inability to create an appropriate column that Cassandra is happy to put my Nippy-encoded data into!

Is there something I'm missing (my code currently)?

```
(def alia-cluster (cluster {:contact-points ["127.0.0.1"]}))

(def session (connect alia-cluster))

(execute session
         (create-keyspace :ks
                          (if-not-exists)
                          (with {:replication {:class "SimpleStrategy"
                                               :replication_factor 1}})))

(execute session
         (use-keyspace :ks))

(execute session
         (create-table :d
                       (if-not-exists)
                       (column-definitions [[:k :XXXXX]
                                            [:primary-key :k]])))

(set-nippy-collection-encoder!)

(set-nippy-decoder!)
```

I have tried just about everything in XXXX - but nothing seems to work!

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Cheers!

Comment: What error messages are you getting when you try to insert into :k?

Comment: I tracked it down to an error in `bind`. If I use `:blob` in XXX (because I do not seem able to use `:bytes`) I get a binding error at runtime:
  Prepared statement has only 1 variables, 314 values provided

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to insert each byte as a column. Can you post a reproducible sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think :bytes is a valid type in CQL it should be :blob. That said there was a bug in the nippy codec (which was marked as experimental). It's now fixed, if you pull 2.5.2 this should work:

```
(use 'qbits.alia)
(use 'qbits.alia.codec.nippy)

(def c (cluster {:contact-points ["localhost"]}))
(def s (connect c))

(set-nippy-decoder!)
(set-nippy-collection-encoder!)

(execute s "use ks;")
(execute s "insert into d (k) values (?);" {:values [[1 2 3]]})
(execute s "select * from d;")
```

(this should work just fine with hayt too)

cheers

Comment: thank you. I am now able to use `:blob` in my code above and substitution in my prepared statements.